# Some basic dictionary usage, how to access elements.

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I have a dictionary with some basic info, below

```
people = {  
'Andrew': ['red', 2],
'Angela': ['purple', 4],
...
}
```

I'm trying to have a user if they enter andrew then it will report back

Andrew is in the directory, his favorite color is red and his favorite number is 2.

not really sure how to access the correct values.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
people = {'Andrew': ['red', 2], 'Angela': ['purple', 4]}
while True:
    user_input = input().strip()
    if user_input in people:
         print(user_input, 'is in the directory, his favorite color is', people[user_input][0], \
                 'and his favorite number is', str(people[user_input][1]))
```